# Add HTTPS support for an application running its own web server, under a non standard HTTP port

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, http

I have a server running Debian 10.
It runs Apache 2.4 for a a web services accessible under `https://example.com`, thanks to a LetsEncrypt certificate.

But it also runs an app (Subsonic) which serves a web UI on port 4040, under its own webserver, as I have no vhost for it and as it is still accessible when Apache is stopped.
So for now the app is accessible under HTTP on `http://example.com:4040`.

I know how to add SSL support for an Apache vhost, but how can I add HTTPS support for it this app, so that it is accessible on `https://example.com:4040` or `https://example.com:1234`?

Also, should I use a different SSL certificate than the one I already have for this domain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a reverse proxy in front of the app and configure HTTPS on this proxy.  Conveniently, you have Apache running which can happily reverse proxy for you.

As it currently stands, you can't use port 4040 as that's already taken by the app, so unless you can change the app's port or get it to bind to localhost (127.0.0.1 etc) only, then you'll have to run this app on a different port.  On that note, if you want to run this app over HTTPS there's no point leaving it still accessible by the insecure HTTP, so it would be better to configure this app to bind to localhost and have it accessible only through the reverse proxy.

You need the `ProxyPass` family of configuration options to create a reverse proxy.  Here's an incomplete example:

```
Listen <Public IP address of server>:4040

<VirtualHost *:4040>

  Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
  ServerName example.com

  SSLEngine On

  # LetsEncrypt certificates (if not configured in another file)
  #  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  #  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/eample.com/privkey.pem
  #  Include               /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4040/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4040/

</VirtualHost>
```

Certificates need to have the hostname that the client uses to connect embedded within their Subject Alternative Names extension, therefore as you don't seem to be proposing a different host (`example.com` in both cases) you won't need a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks, reverse proxy with existing Apache is indeed what I need! One last thing, I'm still a bit confused about "binding to localhost". Does that mean the app wouldn't listen to external network anymore? Also, on your example, 4040 would be the external HTTPS port, right?

Comment: Yes on both counts.  The app only listens locally and any external traffic hits the proxy on port 4040 before it forwards it to the app.  It can do this as the proxy is local too.

Comment: Got it. One last thing, do those virtualhost config lines have to be added to the existing virtual host config file for HTTPS, like example.com-le-ssl.conf?

Comment: You can either add them to an existing config or create another.  Just check how any _other_ ones are enabled in your distro though.

Comment: I got an an Apache error regarding the "Listen" line: "Listen cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section". Should I use this line outside of the section?

Comment: Apologies - the `listen` directive is in the server config context, not virtual host.  Some distros have their `listen` directive in a separate file, such as `ports.conf`.